# Search on two indexed field in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have an log table in below,

```
CREATE TABLE log (    
"date" text,     
"timestamp" timestamp, 
"eventId" text, 
"message" text,
"module" text,
"userId" text,
"ovirtEventId" text, 
"category" text, 
primary key ("date","timestamp","eventId")) with clustering order by ("timestamp" DESC);
```

It is partitioned based on date so it is scaling perfectly,

I did the indexing on the following fields,

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX module_idx ON log ("module") USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer', 'case_sensitive': 'false'};

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX user_idx ON log ("userId")  USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer', 'case_sensitive': 'false'};

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX message_idx ON log ("message")  USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer', 'case_sensitive': 'false'};

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX event_category_idx ON log ("category")  USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer', 'case_sensitive': 'false'};
```

The following query works,

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE date = '20180223' AND "message" LIKE '%This%';
```

But when I try to query on two indexed field, It fails,

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE date = '20180223' AND "message" LIKE '%This%' AND module LIKE 'test';
```

Is there a way to search on two indexed field, please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like's and scanning over secondary indexes are not cassandra's strong points.

You may instead want to run cassandra as your storage engine and have solr or elastic search infront of it.

So with the warning out of the way, you may be able to do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE log_idx (
"date" text, 
"timestamp" timestamp, 
"eventId" text, 
"message" text,
"module" text,
"userId" text,
"ovirtEventId" text, 
"category" text, 
primary key (module, date), timestamp, eventId) with clustering order by ("timestamp" DESC);


CREATE CUSTOM INDEX message_log_idx ON log ("message")  USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer', 'case_sensitive': 'false'};

SELECT * FROM log_idx WHERE module='x' AND date='y' AND message LIKE '%z';
```

This isn't exactly what you want as we've made the consession that your module can no longer be in a LIKE clause and instead must be hardcoded.  You would would fall back on your previous log table if you wanted to just scan over messages across all modules.

Alternatively you could filter at the application layer.

Comment: Adding to that answer, you can also look at elassandra or stratio-lucene plugin. Those two options integrate with Cassandra, and you won't need an additional search-dedicated cluster

Comment: Yeah i was specifically thinking of elassandra.